# Sonar cube:Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large inputsRegular expressions should not overflow the stack

Tags: java, sonarqube

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Klsq.png)

I have used email and web validation .
for email I am using below code

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 191)
@Pattern(regexp = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\\.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$")
private String email;
```

//for web address validation I have used following expression

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 191)
@Pattern(regexp = "^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\w\\.]+)\\.([a-z]{2,6}\\.?)(\\/[\\w\\.]*)*\\/?$")
private String webAddress;
```

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66532068/7804477

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) Also for email address validation try using `@Email` instead of `@Pattern`